# JavaScript: Cache multiple Classes as Single Variable

Tags: javascript, caching

Is there a way to cache multiple classes as a single variable.

For example, let's say I have two divs like this:

```
<div class="MYCLASS"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

what would be the best way to cache either of these as a single variable with javascript? Would something like this work?

```
var multipleclasses = document.querySelector("myclass, MYCLASS");
```

Or is the syntax like this:

```
var multipleclasses = document.querySelector("myclass" || "MYCLASS");
```

Or would you have to cache them individually:

```
var multipleclasses = document.querySelector("MYCLASS");
var multipleclasses = document.querySelector("myclass");
```

Lastly, is there a way to select a class irrespective of its letter case ?:

```
var multipleclasses = document.querySelector("myclass"); // select any case??
```

Note - I want to select either classes, not both.

**NO jQuery please**

Comment: I was of the impression a variable will cache the process of referencing the element. If you don't use a variable, the reference is run each time you use it. No?

Comment: Yes, but the word is not *cache*. As you said, is a reference in the local scope. Refresh the page and is lost.

Comment: Ok I see, what I meant was caching the reference inside a script. So what word do you use, if not cache? I've seen lots of people use the word cache for variables.

Comment: Well, thinking on [general uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) it can be called cache in a rude form, but when saying about [web development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache), I think that is no so right. Anyway, call it the way you want. I like *reference* word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to use `querySelectorAll` to return multiple elements. Second, to match a class name you have to use the prefix `.`; a word without a prefix matches a tag name.

```
var multipleclasses = document.querySelectorAll(".myclass, .MYCLASS");
```

That is correct.

```
var multipleclasses = document.querySelectorAll(".myclass" || ".MYCLASS");
```

This evaluates the logical expression `".myclass" || ".MYCLASS"`, and passes this as an argument to `document.querySelectorAll`. So it's equivalent to:

```
var multipleClasses = document.querySelectorAll(".myclass");
```

If you do:

```
var multipleclasses = document.querySelectorAll(".MYCLASS");
var multipleclasses = document.querySelectorAll(".myclass");
```

the second assignment overwrites the variable, so you just get the result of the second assignment.

You could do it as two separate calls, and concatenate the results into an array:

```
var multipleclasses1 = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".MYCLASS"));
var multipleclasses2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".myclass"));
var multipleclasses = multipleclasses1.concat(multipleclasses2);
```

There's no way to perform case-insensitive class matching automatically.

Comment: So the first variable example would select either, even if one is not present?

Comment: yes, just like when you use comma in CSS. It selects everything that matches either of the selectors.

Comment: Ahh I see. So the syntax inside the commas will always follow CSS syntax?

Comment: Yes. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) says: _selectors is a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas._

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I was a little confused. Much clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `querySelectorAll` method to match multiple elements. Use periods in front of the class names in the query syntax:

```
var multipleclasses = document.querySelectorAll(".myclass, .MYCLASS");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/q3yyK/

If you want only the first element found, the `querySelector` method works, with the right query syntax:

```
var multipleclasses = document.querySelector(".myclass, .MYCLASS");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cache them in an Array:

```
var multipleclasses = [
    document.querySelector("MYCLASS"),
    document.querySelector("myclass")
];
```

Comment: Does this store both of them or either of them? For example if "MYCLASS" wasn't present, but "myclass" was, would it still select the latter?

Comment: This results in a 2-dimensional array (actually, an array of NodeLists), so he'd have to use nested loops to iterate over all of them. Probably not ideal.

Comment: @Barmar he'l have to iterate over the collection anyway no matter how he stores it.

Comment: @user3143218 if `MYCLASS` is not present, `querySelector` will return null, and the array will hold `[null, <the myclass object>]`

Comment: @Barmar: THe `querySelector` method doesn't return a NodeList.